# Does Genesis 19:14 mean Lot had some daughters who were already married or not?

Tags: genesis

Genesis 19:14 reads differently in different versions of the Bible.  Some versions speak of Lot's sons-in-law as if they are pledged to the virgin daughters living with him (v. 8), while other versions imply that Lot had other daughters who were already married. Which is the correct translation of this verse?

> So Lot went out and said to his sons-in-law, who were to marry his daughters.... (ESV)
>
> And Lot went out, and spake unto his sons in law, which married his daughters... (KJV)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here.  Please consider [registering an account](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) to fully take advantage of what this site has to offer.  Also, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on  how this site is [a little different](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives#803) than other sites around the web. *This is not a comment on the quality of your question, but rather a standard welcome message.*

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How many daughters did Lot have, two or four?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/12750/3555)

Answer (score 0):

I use the King James Version exclusively.  It would appear that Lot had at least 4 daughters.  The sons-in-laws were told to leave this place because it would be destroyed. Verse 14.   then in verse 15, the next morning the two unmarried daughters, which are here, were taken out of danger.  That assumes that there were other daughters elsewhere.